# idToken is empty string when calling "getUserInfo()" (safe auth kit using outdated web3auth version?)

Tags: gnosis-safe, web3auth

I am developing a Dapp using [safe auth kit](https://docs.safe.global/reference/auth-kit), and recently found that the idToken is empty when calling `await web3AuthModalPack.getUserInfo()` (like in this [example repo](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/auth-kit/example/src/App.tsx#L101))

My Dapp relies on the idToken to verify a users login and create an admin-signed signature in the backend. Without this I cannot run any further API calls from the client :(

The web3 auth forums **recommend upgrading to 6.1.7** as this *may* solve the issue. (see here https://web3auth.io/community/t/getuserinfo-on-social-login-does-not-return-idtoken/4546/4)

I noticed running `yarn` produces the following warnings in safe-auth kit (safe auth kit is using an outdated vesion of web3auth 4.6.0):
[image]

These are my current dependencies:

```
"@safe-global/api-kit": "^1.3.1",
"@safe-global/auth-kit": "^1.2.1",
"@safe-global/protocol-kit": "^1.3.0",
"@walletconnect/client": "^1.8.0",
"@web3auth/base": "^6.1.7",
"@web3auth/modal": "^6.1.7",
"@web3auth/openlogin-adapter": "^6.1.7",
```

Any help is appreciated!